# R - Remove text from column name after [ symbol

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R called hues

It has 3 columns called color1 [primary],  color2 [secondary], color3 [tertiary]

I have tried using sub / gsub etc, but have not found a solution

Anyone able to help?

```
names(hues) = gsub(pattern = "\\[*", replacement = "", x = names(hues))
```

I Have this

```
color1 [primary]     color2 [secondary]    color3 [tertiary]
blue                pink                  red
```

I want this

```
color1              color2                color3 
blue                pink                  red
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `.` before `*`, to indicate that you want replace any number of characters after `[`. Also add a space before `\\[` to remove that space too. I made the column names into a character vector but replace `ex` with `names(hues)` for your `hues` dataframe, and obviously assign it back since it is just printing the output here.

```r
ex <- c("color1 [primary]", "color2 [secondary]", "color3 [tertiary]")
gsub(" \\[.*", "", ex)
#> [1] "color1" "color2" "color3"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

That's an overkill here, but perhaps it may be useful to know a solution with `stringr` as well:

```
library(stringr)

names(hues) = word(names(hues), 1)
```

Output:

```
  color1 color2 color3
1   blue   pink    red
```

Data used:

```
hues <- data.frame("color1 [primary]" = c("blue"), 
                 "color2 [secondary]" = c("pink"), 
                 "color3 [tertiary]" = c("red"), check.names = F)
```